# Transact SQL - Table with different Record types requiring calculation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table of invoices and Record_Types that I need to reconcile to open invoice report.  I have the process down and know what I need to do.  Just dont know how to properly structure the query and would prefer to not create 3 tables.
Record Types.

- Invoice = 1 Credit = 5 Payment = 7

Invoice_Number, Record_Type, Dollar figure

Outstanding_Balance = Invoice(1) -(Payment(7)-(Credit))

Invoice_number  Record_type Gen_Numeric_3

Basically I need to take the record_Type 1 and subtract the total of record type 7's from the below.

```
Invoice_Num Rec_Type Dollar_Amt    
00820437      1     536.7700000000  
00820437      7     469.6200000000  
00820437      7      67.1500000000
```

Any advice would be great.  messer

Comment: Please read what you wrote and without assuming you know what you are trying to do. The line about "invoice_number Record_type Gen_Numeric_3" means nothing to anyone else. Is it relevant at all? And according to your formula you effectively want to **add* credits (given "<1> - (<7> - 5>) which is the same as <1> - <7> + <5>) . Correct? How about providing a more comprehensive set of sample data and the result you expect?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with aggregation and case statements:

```
SELECT invoice_num, 
   SUM(CASE WHEN rec_type = 1 THEN dollar_amt ELSE 0 END) - (SUM(CASE WHEN rec_type=7 THEN dollar_amt ELSE 0 END) - SUM(CASE WHEN rec_type=5 THEN dollar_amt ELSE 0 END)) as outstanding_balance
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY invoice_num
```

Comment: With a couple tweaks I am squared away.  Cant tell you how much I appreciate your time.  Thank you so very much.  Sincerely. Esser

Comment: @messer - please mark it as an answer then. If there's tweaks added you can add to comments